# Reordering Category Layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, style

[image]I was wondering if there is a way to reorganize the layers when applying a style based on a categorizing value?  I have many values, but I would like to rearrange them alphabetically.  In ArcMap there are arrows to promote, or demote the values in the list, but I do not see anything like this in QGIS 1.8.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the top of the column to sort ascending, click again to sort descending.  At least this works with QGIS 1.7.4.  Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to manually move classifications up or down.

Comment: Yes, that is in the Attribute Table.  I want it in the Properties Window, so that it is reflected in the Table of Contents for my Legend.

Comment: Layer properties, style tab . . . change single symbol to categorized . . . choose your column, then click Classify.  You should be able to sort ascending/descending on Value and Label.

Comment: I did try that, but it is not reflected in the Layers TOC (see posted image).  Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean.

Comment: You could try a nightly build.  Evidently it works (or will work) in version 2.0.0  http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4299

Answer (score 0):

I think these can be reordered by drag and drop. I sometimes use this for geological maps.